# Thread in Jersey 2

Tags: java, jersey, jersey-2.0

In Jersey 2.22, with the following code:

```
@Path("/header")
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    public Response get(){
    ...
    }

    @Path("sub")
    public Sub sub(){
        return new Sub();
    }
}

public class Sub {

    @GET
    public Response get(){
    ...
    }

    @Path("sub")
    public SubSub sub(){
        return new SubSub();
    }
}

public class SubSub {

    @GET
    public Response get(){
    ...
    }

    @Path("sub")
    public SubSubSub sub(){
        return new SubSubSub();
    }
}

public class SubSubSub {

    @GET
    public Response get(){
    ...
    }
}
```

Is it guaranteed that for `/header/sub/sub/sub`, the same thread will be used when traversing from `TestResource.sub()` all the way to `SubSubSubSubSubSubSub`...'s `get()` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about threading you should use an AsyncResource to handle things like thread pooling and timeouts.

```
@POST
@Path("bid/{exchangeId}/{key}")
public void handleBid(@PathParam("exchangeId") final String exchangeId, @PathParam("key") final String key,
            final OrtbBidRequest request, @Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse) throws FilterException, IOException {

    // Timeout for clarity.
    asyncResponse.setTimeout(timeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    asyncResponse.setTimeoutHandler(timeoutHandler);

    // Sending no data as an example
    asyncResponse.resume(Response.noContent().build());
}
```

This example here allows me to send a message to a message queue for handling. The async response will allow you to handle async threading however you want. BTW unless you create a new thread of execution it will be the same thread executing the code. If it is orthogonal.